# как вставить иконку в кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

создавая динамически кнопку button с помощью jquery:

```
var mybutton = $('<button/>',
{
    text: 'Click Me',
    click: function () { alert('Hello Habr'); }
}).appendTo('.content');
```

как в кнопку можно вставить иконку `<i class="fa fa-ban"></i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов. Есть свойство **html**, в которое можно вставить **html**.

```js
var mybutton = $('<button/>', {
  html: '<i class="fa fa-ban">icon</i> Click Me',
  click: function() {
    alert('Hello Habr');
  }
}).appendTo('.content')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, не знал что вместо text можно использовать html